# What is the WGA compensation when multiple writers work on the same episode?

Tags: screenwriting, money

I understand that if you want to hire a writer to write an episode there are certain minimums set, like $15k for a 20min sitcom story plus teleplay. But, what if there are multiple writers writing a single episode, what happens then? Do both writers get $15k?

Answer (score 2):

If multiple writers have written a script they are "considered a unit" and get paid as if they were one person.

> If more than one writer shares the story or teleplay
>   credit, then all of the writers sharing each credit shall be considered
>   a unit and shall participate equally and receive in the aggregate the
>   theatrical exhibition payment applicable thereto, except that in the
>   case of a comedy-variety program, the Guild shall determine the
>   proportions in which such participating writers will share the
>   theatrical exhibition payment, will notify the Company thereof and
>   Company will make payments accordingly.
>   *~ Writers Guild of America 2014 Theatrical and Television Basic Agreement*